# Area Type text box not moving textbox when I click and drag corner anchor point - Illustrator CC

Tags: adobe-illustrator, text, creative-cloud

I am experiencing an issue with my area type text box in illustrator where I can't drag the corner anchor. An icon just appears to carry text into another text box.I used to be able to drag the corner and the text would move to accomodate the size of the text frame but now I can't do it for some reason?

See image below

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm not able to replicate this, it works fine in my copy of AI *(latest update)*.

For some reason, *probably* because of your display settings, and because the text box is small, you *probably* get overlapping handles.

Try to zoom in some more, and make sure you use the corner handle.

[image]

Comment: Hi @Lucian I zoomed in but still couldn't see the handle. I ended up resetting the preferences and it seemed to work again, but not exactly sure what happened so am not sure if the issue is resolved?